# Usage of strdup()

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, free

Let's say we have a struct :

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name){
  struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
  assert(who != NULL);
  who->name = strdup(name);
  return who;
}

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who){
  assert(who != NULL);
  free(who->name);
  free(who);
}
```

And the main function :

```
  int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

  struct Person *mike = Person_create("mike");
  Person_print(mike);
  Person_destroy(mike);

  return 0;
}
```

The above code won't work properly without the strdup() function. Valgrind says that the address you try to free with free(who->name) is not malloc'd. What's the story behind this, didn't I malloc'd that memory when I malloc'd the struct? And what difference does the strdup() make?

Comment: are you sure this corresponds to your test case?

Comment: yes, original code was more complicated but when I run this program it says "*** Error in `./ex1': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000004006fd ***"

Comment: this code looks ok. There are two options here. Either `Person_print` does some nasty writes, which I doubt, or your program is different to this test case.

Comment: Another option is I didn't read the question to the end. Of course if you don't `strdup` and keep the `free` you'll get some troubles. The `free` is present only because `strdup` calls `malloc` to duplicate the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code each `Person` object involves two independent blocks of memory: the `struct Person` object itself and the separate memory block for the name. That separate memory block is pointed by the `name` pointer inside the struct. When you allocate `struct Person` by using `malloc`, you are not allocating any memory for the name. It is, again, an independent block of memory that should be allocated independently.

How you are planning to allocate memory for the name is entirely up to you. If you use `strdup` (which is essentially a wrapper for `malloc`) as in your code above, then you will have to free it by `free` in the end.

You did not explain what you mean by "without the strdup() function". What did you code look like without it? If you simply did

```
who->name = name;
```

then you made that `who->name` pointer to point directly to the string literal memory occupied by literal `"mike"`. String literals reside in static memory. You are not allowed to `free` them. This is what valgrind is telling you.

Comment: Yes actually, that was the case, deleting the line free(who->name) solves all errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mallocing the struct allocates memory for the pointer name but it doesn't allocate any memory for name to point to.  At that point who->name will be some random garbage value so freeing it makes no sense.

strdup uses malloc internally to allocate memory for the string it copies. Once you've got a pointer back from strdup you can, and should, free it when you're done.

Answer (score -3):

strdup do noes call malloc, it is only string operation. you only malloc the pointer to the struct ,not the inner member

Comment: The documentation disagrees: "Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3)."